# Get html element by value

Tags: c#

Given the following html in a Winforms Webbrowser DOM, I'm attempting to get the second element with `value="type102"`

```
    <div class="Input"><input type="radio" name="type" value="type101" 
onclick="setType('type101');"><a href="javaScript:setType('type101');" 
onclick="s_objectID=&quot;javascript:setType('type101');_1&quot;;return this.s_oc?
this.s_oc(e):true">type101</a></div>

    <div class="Input"><input type="radio" name="type" value="type102" 
onclick="setType('type102');" checked="checked"><a href="javaScript:setType('type102');" 
onclick="s_objectID=&quot;javascript:setType('type102');_1&quot;;return this.s_oc?
this.s_oc(e):true">type102</a></div>
```

I've used 
`HtmlElement htmlElem = browser.Document.GetElementById(....`

and

`HtmlElement htmlElem = browser.Document.All.GetElementsByName(....`

before, but in this instance they are both the same so would need to get by value or href

Is it possible to get the second element directly without external libraries or would I have to get a collection of GetElementsByName and iterate through them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
HtmlElementCollection col=  webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input");
HtmlElement wanted;

foreach (HtmlElement item in col)
{
    if (item.GetAttribute("value")=="type102")
    {
        wanted = item;
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var elems = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input");
var myInputElement = elems.First(e => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(e) && e.Trim().ToLower().Equals("type102"));
foreach (var elem in elems)
{
    var value = elem.GetAttribute("value");
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) && value.Trim().ToLower().Equals("type102"))
    {
        MessageBox.Show(value);
        break;
    }
}
```

Or to make it shorter

```
var elems = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input");
var myInputElement = elems.First(e => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(e) && e.Trim().ToLower().Equals("type102"));
```

Is this what you are looking for? you can also have a look at [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) for things like these.

Answer (score 1):

```
HtmlElement htmlElem = browser.Document.All.GetElementsByName(...)[1]
```