# How to retrieve the value from HTML

Tags: c#, html

I'm trying to extract the value from an HTML string in a console application.

This [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmlelement.getattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) almost explains what I want, as does this [Get html element by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12935398/get-html-element-by-value)

In my console application, my function looks like

```
    public void MyMethod()
    {
        var myValue = GetValueFromHtml("<a href=\"#\">My Link</a>");
    }

    internal string GetValueFromHtml(code)
    {
       //mycode   
       //returns My Link
    }
```

I can do this using string manipulation, splitting on the first `>` and then on this new values first '<'.

I guess I could also try and convert it to XDocument (although expections are thrown about illegal characters but that my be workable still) but overall it seems a little overkill? I tried using XElement but that complains since I have `<` tags

I'm asuming that I could use the HtmlElement.GetValue() to achieve the same thing but I don't know how when I'm not working an array/List?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you to use [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) (available from NuGet):

```
string html = "<a href=\"#\">My Link</a>";
var node = HtmlNode.CreateNode(html);
string value = node.InnerHtml; // "My Link"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
string html = "<a href=\"#\">My Link</a>";
XElement elem = XElement.Parse(html);
Console.WriteLine(elem.Value);  // output: My Link
```

Comment: Note - html is not xml. While this code works for sample input, it will fail for other valid html, e.g. `<a href="#">My Link<br></a>`

Comment: Although the package suggested by Sergey fulfills the needs, this is great because it means I don't need another 3rd party plugin/software. It also shows I could have used XElement and providing I'm careful it may work although I wonder if it will work with <a href="#">My Link<br /></a> (since I use XHTML)... I guess I need to test it